# Angular 7 PDFJS Component

Tags: angular, pdf.js

I'm trying to wrap up PDFJS inside of an Angular 7 component.  I have the following code, but PDFJS is undefined.  I'm building the app using Angular/CLI.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild, Input } from '@angular/core';
declare let PDFJS: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dsgpdf',
  templateUrl: './dsgpdf.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dsgpdf.component.scss']
})
export class DsgpdfComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('theCanvas', { read: ElementRef }) theCanvas;


    constructor() {


    }

    ngOnInit() {
        debugger;
        //
        // If absolute URL from the remote server is provided, configure the CORS
        // header on that server.
        //
        var url = '/assets/fdcc0545-a0d7-4c30-89ef-5a908a1e2a47.pdf';
        //
        // The workerSrc property shall be specified.
        //

        let pdfWorkerSrc: string = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.0.943/pdf.worker.min.js';



        PDFJS.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = pdfWorkerSrc;
        //
        // Asynchronous download PDF
        //
        var loadingTask = PDFJS.getDocument(url);
        loadingTask.then(pdf => {
            //
            // Fetch the first page
            //
            pdf.getPage(2).then(page => {
                var scale = 1.5;
                var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
                //
                // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
                //
                var canvas = this.theCanvas.nativeElement;
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                canvas.height = viewport.height;
                canvas.width = viewport.width;
                //
                // Render PDF page into canvas context
                //
                var renderContext = {
                    canvasContext: context,
                    viewport: viewport,
                };
                page.render(renderContext).then(() => {
                    debugger;
                });
            });
        });
  }

}
```

I've also tried adding this line of code:

```
let PDFJS: any = require('pdfjs-dist/build/pdf');
```

But, it fails to compile:

```
 error TS2580: Cannot find name 'require'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node`.
```

I'm clearly importing this incorrectly.  Can someone point me in the right direction.

Secondary question:  I don't want to load the worker from a cdn.  What's the right way to do this when using Angular/CLI?

Answer (score 2):

There are no targeted angular components for PDFJS. Configuration needs extra steps and not very straight forward. If you are willing to bring an extra angular npm package, Here are few packages the open source community has created as alternatives.

The below package will help you integrate pdfjs into your angular 7. It does provide the base functionality, does not provide a viewer. Highly configurable: [ng2-pdf-viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer).

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 @Component({
  selector: 'example-app',
  template: `
  <div>
      <label>PDF src</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="PDF src" [(ngModel)]="pdfSrc">
  </div>
  <pdf-viewer [src]="pdfSrc" 
              [render-text]="true"
              style="display: block;"
  ></pdf-viewer>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  pdfSrc: string = '/pdf-test.pdf';
}
```

Also, there is another package - [ng2-pdfjs-viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdfjs-viewer) which provides a viewer as well - full disclosure, it is created by me.

Usage is like this.

```
<!-- your.component.html -->
<button (click)="openPdf();">Open Pdf</button>

<ng2-pdfjs-viewer #pdfViewer style="width: 800px; height: 400px"
  [pdfJsFolder]="'pdfjs'"
  [externalWindow]="true"
  [downloadFileName]="'mytestfile.pdf'"
  [download]="false">
</ng2-pdfjs-viewer>

<!-- your.component.ts-->
export class RateCardComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('pdfViewer') pdfViewer;
  ...

  private downloadFile(url: string): any {
    return this.http.get(url, { responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob }).map(
      (res) => {
        return new Blob([res.blob()], { type: "application/pdf" });
      });
  }

  public openPdf() {
    let url = "url to fetch pdf as byte array";
    // url can be local url or remote http request to an api/pdf file. 
    // E.g: let url = "assets/pdf-sample.pdf";
    // E.g: https://github.com/intbot/ng2-pdfjs-viewer/tree/master/sampledoc/pdf-sample.pdf
    // E.g: http://localhost:3000/api/GetMyPdf
    // Please note, for remote urls to work, CORS should be enabled at the server. Read: https://enable-cors.org/server.html

    this.downloadFile(url).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        this.pdfViewer.pdfSrc = res; // pdfSrc can be Blob or Uint8Array
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: just for anyone who reach here, `ng2-pdf-viewer` is not working with Angular SSR

Comment: Thank you for creating a library `ng2-pdfjs-viewer`. With the library I am facing few issues, can you take a look at the latest issues opened by me `faizaldong` ? thanks!

Comment: @Fai Zal Dong - I have the same problem. did you find any solution for angular universal

Answer (score 0):

in order to include pdfjs in your angular project, after you install the package by using something like `npm i pdfjs-dist`, you will need to modify your `angular.json` file, to put the all filepath in `scripts` section.

to avoid angular complaining about not found the `PDFjs` (if that's the object name), you will need to add something like `declare var PDFjs` in the component where you want to use it

Comment: Ok, I added pdf.min.js to angular.json in the script section, as denoted in the edit of the original question.  I also added declare var PDFJS;  It compiles, but PDFJS is still undefined.

Comment: @Darthg8r  i installed pdfjs-dist, then I `declared var pdfjsLib` 
in my app component file, its outside the class, then I can console.log(pdfjsLib) to see an object, you may want to check their document to look for the object's name you want to use

Comment: @lucas March 2021, your method not working

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to download the pdf.js script and add it in somewhere in assets folder. Then, in the scripts array of Angular.json do something like:
`"scripts": ["src/assets/js/pdf.js"]`